# C language: main .obj file (and executable) is nearly 400MB in size

Tags: c

Dependencies:

- GLFW 3.3.7
- GLAD 4.0 core
- CGLM 0.8.5
- stb_image 2.2.7

Compiler: GCC 11.2.0 (MinGW-W64)
CMake 3.23.1
GNU Make 4.3

## Problem

The .obj file for main.c (and executable) is nearly 400MB in size
Generated .obj files: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dgn51.png

There must something wrong with the main.c file and/or the way I include my dependency headers, but I can't figure it out.

## Source

**The full source can be found at this github repo** https://github.com/kvbc/maincraft

main.c

```c
#include "mc.h"

#define GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

mc.h

```c
#ifndef MC_H
#define MC_H

#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <cglm/cglm.h>
#include <stb_image.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

#include "config.h"
```

## Building

I'm using CMake and Make to build GLFW and CGLM as static libraries and my program into an executable.
As far as I'm aware there's no problem with building the first two, but here is how I do it

```
cmake -S lib/glfw-3.3.7 -B build/glfw -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DGLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF -DGLFW_BUILD_TESTS=OFF -DGLFW_BUILD_DOCS=OFF
make -C build/glfw
:: CGLM
cmake -S lib/cglm-0.8.5 -B build/cglm -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DCGLM_SHARED=OFF -DCGLM_STATIC=ON -DCGLM_USE_C99=OFF -DCGLM_USE_TEST=OFF
make -C build/cglm
```

Now, as for building my code (CMakeLists.txt)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8.2)

project(maincraft)

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-O3 -s -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wextra")

include_directories(lib/glfw-3.3.7/include)
include_directories(lib/cglm-0.8.5/include)
include_directories(lib/glad-4.0-core/include)
include_directories(lib/stb_image-2.2.7/include)

link_directories(build/glfw/src)
link_directories(build/cglm)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
    lib/stb_image-2.2.7/src/stb_image.c
    lib/glad-4.0-core/src/glad.c
    src/file.c
    src/main.c
    src/program.c
    src/camera.c
    src/world.c
    src/tex.c
    src/math.c
    src/text.c
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} glfw3)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} cglm)
```

The stb_image.c file is just a define with an include

```
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include <stb_image.h>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow ! Please add code, commands, and outputs as text, not as links to pictures.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions. Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: @limserhane god you're right what am i doing

Comment: And [*no images of code*](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) (or any text really).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `main.c` file you have the global variable `G`, which is a structure containing many other structures.

Among other things the `G` structure have a member named `world` which is a `mc_World` structure.

The `mc_World` structure have an array of `10000000` elements, each element being a `mc_Block` structure.

The `mc_Block` structure is at least 32 bytes large.

The `mc_World` array `block` will take up at least `32 * 10000000` bytes, i.e. just a little under 320 MiB!

As an array (indirectly) in the global scope it will exist in the object file, and in the executable file.

Perhaps you should consider dynamic allocation for this array? That will also make it easier to have a world of different sizes.

Comment: All this wouldn't be that problematic, as data structures that are all zero don't take up place in the executable. But then there's that `.mouse.moved = MC_TRUE` in there, which means the structure is *not* all zero, and has to be initialized from `.data` instead of `.bss`...

Comment: Lowering that value did it, I set a really bizzare value just to test out the performance and forgot to change it. I'm extremely embarrassed and sorry you had to go through my code

Comment: @DevSolar Instead of setting that value in the initializer, I set it just before the main loop and size of the executable has decreased by 800 times. I will now be more cautious about initializng my structs, thanks!